# FinishLocation Help For Visualforce & Flow

Tags: visualforce

I have custom buttons that call a VForce page that passes the selected record ids on a related list into a flow to update a field. However, when the flow finishes, it returns the user to the tab of the parent custom object, not the parent record the related list was on.

How can I accomplish this? I'm not a developer and had a lot of help putting this together.

VForce Code

```
<apex:page StandardController="Sample_Order_Line_Items__c" tabstyle="Sample_Order_Line_Items__c" recordSetVar="SOLI" >

<apex:repeat value="{!SOLI}" var="row" rendered="false">
    {!row.id}
    {!row.Status__c}
</apex:repeat>

<flow:interview name="SOLIComplete"
      finishLocation="{!URLFOR($Action.Sample_Order__c.Tab, $ObjectType.Sample_Order__c)}">
    <apex:param name="Selected" value="{!Selected}"/>
</flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Seems like the `finishLocation` would need to include the ID of a specific record you want to return to. Right now it looks like it is just the generic URL for a Sample_Order__c tab.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an extension controller that will read the parent records id from the URL.

```
<apex:page StandardController="Sample_Order_Line_Items__c" tabstyle="Sample_Order_Line_Items__c" 
        recordSetVar="SOLI" extensions="SomeExtension" >

    <apex:repeat value="{!SOLI}" var="row" rendered="false">
        {!row.id}
        {!row.Status__c}
    </apex:repeat>

    <flow:interview name="SOLIComplete"
          finishLocation="{!parentId}">
        <apex:param name="Selected" value="{!Selected}"/>
    </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

SomeExtension class:

```
public class SomeExtension {

    public PageReference getParentId() {
        Id parentId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        return new PageReference('/' + parentId);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

All, it turned out all i needed was:

```
finishLocation="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.retURL}">
```

I know it wont work in LEx, but we're in classic for the time being and needed to fix the issue so we could operate efficiently. Will address down the road when we migrate.

Thank you!